# Methods to produce solvable deals in Klondike solitaire?

Tags: computer-ai, klondike-solitaire

About 20% of Klondike-solitaire deals are not solvable.  My question is **what is the best method to get solvable deals**?

I thought about two options:

1. Deal a random permutation, then try to solve it with a solver, if failed, re-deal. (requires a solver like [‘Solvitaire’](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.12314.pdf))
2. Go back from the winning state, use random reverse moves until we get to a starting state. (needs a tool that produce random reverse-moves)

Reference: [The Winnability of Klondike Solitaire and Many Other Patience Games](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.12314.pdf)